# How to define an optional List of class as one of the fields in Avro Schema to avoid Avro-Serialization error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, avro

**My Requirement is to store the data in database:** If `addresses` is being sent as request via Postman, then `currentAddress` and `previousAddresses` should not be sent & if both are sent, then `addresses` should not be sent at all.

**Addresses, PreviousAddresses and CurrentAddress are defined as:**

```
private List<MyClassOldAddress> addresses;
private List<MyClassAddress> previousAddresses;
private MyClassAddress currentAddress;
```

**What I did:**
I have defined an Avro-Schema (using v1.11.1) like below which is getting converted into Java Class to be used by an API where we sent the request body to store the data in database.

```
{
   "namespace":"com.avro.data",
   "type":"record",
   "name":"MyClass",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"userId",
         "type":"string",
         "docs":"This is the unique id for user."
      },
      {
         "name":"middleName",
         "type":[
            "null",
            "string"
         ],
         "avro.java.string":"String"
      },
      {
         "name":"firstName",
         "type":"string",
         "avro.java.string":"String"
      },
      {
         "name":"lastName",
         "type":"string",
         "avro.java.string":"String"
      },
      {
         "name":"addresses",
         "type":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":"com.data.MyClassAddress"
         },
         "default": []
      },
      {
         "name":"previousAddresses",
         "type":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":"com.data.MyClassOtherAddress"
         },
         "default": []
      },
      {
      "name": "currentAddress",
      "type": [
            "null",
            "com.data.MyClassOtherAddress"
            ],
      "default": null
    }
   ]
}
```

When I pass the request from Postman and send the fields `addresses` or `currentAddress` or `previousAddresses` as null or empty [] as per requirement like below, it is throwing some errors:

**REQUEST 1:**

```
{
   "userId":"123",
   "middle_name":"user_middle_name",
   "first_name":"user_first_name",
   "last_name":"user_last_name",
   "addresses":[
      {
         "street_name":"testing",
         "town":"testing",
         "country":"ABC",
         "postcode":"123456",
         "house_number":"123",
         "start_date":"2000-01"
      }
   ],
   "previous_addresses":[],
   "current_address":null
}
```

**REQUEST 2:**

```
{
   "userId":"123",
   "middle_name":"user_middle_name",
   "first_name":"user_first_name",
   "last_name":"user_last_name",
   "addresses":[],
   "previous_addresses":[...some data here...],
   "current_address":{...some data here...}
}
```

**Errors:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value for (non-nullable) List\<MyClassAddress\> at
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
```

**My Observation:**
Upon identifying, I came to know that if any field (`addresses` or `currentAddress` or `previousAddresses`) is sent as null or [], it failed to Serialize before storing it in database.

But when I put anything in those objects, it doesn't fail. But I can't do it, I have to set as per requirement.

So, how do I avoid this thing, making all 3 fields in Avro-Schema as an optional fields so that it should not create any issue while serialization?

I tried adding "default:[]", "default: null", "null" but none of them worked! Please help.

I tried sending Request with some condition (when addresses is sent, currentAddress and previousAddresses should not be sent and vice-versa) but it failed in serialization.

I am expecting it to work without serialization error and if fields are missing (as per requirement), it should not fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avro requires strict schema compatibility, which means that the schema used to serialize the data must be exactly the same as the schema used to deserialize the data.
For e.g., when your optional field is missing from the request body (which you are trying to sent via Postman), the deserializer will not be able to match the missing field with the field in the schema, causing Avro schema serialization error.

What I suggest you is to keep a null check with IF condition and create an empty/null constructor of each fields of your optional field/class to avoid missing field in avro schema while deserializing it. This way you are not passing any value in your optional fields of that particular class and on other hand, satisfying the schema fields so that deserializer checks and be content that nothing is missing as per the defined schema.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t miss any field or class used in avro schema avsc file even if it is optional. Just serialize with null value to satifsy the schema formation while serializing because deserializer will look for the skeleton and if anything is missing, it will fail.